# Customized memory allocation and deletion

Tags: c++

```
struct Rational
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct NextOnFreeList
{
    NextOnFreeList *next;
};

// Build the linked-list
NextOnFreeList* freeList = NULL; // head of the linked-list
size_t size = (sizeof(Rational) > sizeof(NextOnFreeList *)) ? sizeof(Rational) : sizeof(NextOnFreeList *);
NextOnFreeList *runner = static_cast <NextOnFreeList *> new char [size]; // LineA
freeList = runner;
for (int i = 0; i < EXPANSION_SIZE; i++) {
    runner->next = static_cast <NextOnFreeList *> new char [size];
    runner = runner->next;
}
runner->next = 0;
```

Question 1> LineA
Since the size of Rational(i.e. 8 bytes) is larger than NextOnFreeList(i.e. 4 bytes),
each element in the Linked-list will ONLY use partial of the allocated memory. Is that correct?

```
// Delete the linked-list

NextOnFreeList *nextPtr = NULL;
for (nextPtr = freeList; nextPtr != NULL; nextPtr = freeList) {
    freeList = freeList->next;
    delete [] nextPtr; // LineB
}
```

Question 2> LineB
why should we use 'delete [] nextPtr' instead of 'delete nextPtr'?

Question 3>

```
Rational* ptr = static_cast<Rational*>( freeList ); // LineC
ptr->a = 10;
ptr->b = 20;
```

Is it true by LineC, we can bring back all the allocated memory original with size of 'size' and
use the memory to store all elements inside the Rational.

Comment: one question at a time.

Comment: Why not use `reinterpret_cast<>`, surely this is more apt? I hope this is not for production code(!) But since you asked, 1. Yes, 2. because you used `new []`, 3. Yes, but don't forget to store `freeList->next` somewhere before you overwrite it..

Comment: @Nim, for Q2> How does the compiler knows that the pointer pointing to NextOnFreeList* is casted from char*?

Comment: @Nim what is the point to put answers into comments?

Comment: @q0987, it doesn't, you have to instruct it explicitly (with the `delete []`), else you'll have a memory leak/UB...

Comment: @Slava, 1. I had a question, 2. Not enough time (have day job to contend with most of the time), (3. Someone would always provide a cleaner answer with more details, barring that when I get time I would have posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** Yes, but I would rather use [`std::allocator<Rational>::allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/allocate) (or `union` of both - you will avoid alignment problems this way)

**Q2:** It is actually bad, because you should cast it to `char*` first, then use `delete[]`. Again, using [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) would be better. **And**: It does not matter on default implementation (calls `free`), but forget I said that ;) ... using `malloc`/`free` directly is safer.

**Q3**:: It is fine, but I am not sure if `static_cast` will allow that (`reinterpret_cast` or casting to `void*` in between may help)

**EDIT**: I hope your **Q3** is not final, because you need to update the free list first (before using the pointer).

**2nd EDIT:** Links + note: hiding the free-list inside the allocator would be best for C++ (using `malloc`/`free` directly in it, or `new[]` / `delete[]`)

Comment: The code is borrowed from 'Efficient C++ Performance Programming Techniques'

Comment: `delete [] (char*)nextPtr` is better, but as I said, `std::allocator<union { Rational r; NextOnFreeList ptr; }>` is best (or `malloc` - it will allocate aligned storage)

Comment: this `std::allocator` concept here is new to me. Do you have a good resource where I can find the in detail information for the usage of `std::allocator`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator - you can customize it, that may be the best way (hide the free-list logic in the allocator)

Comment: This reminds me of my old school project: http://pastebin.com/MrWmhJs5 - I was writing OS for some risc processor and used this in the kernel (allocator for structs - named *same size allocator*)

Answer (score 0):

**Q.1:**

Yes but that is not the best idea to use `static_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` would be more preferable.

**Q.2:**
I dont there is a defined behavior to recognize your `static_cast` to accept a simple `delete`. safest way would be to look at this as the original allocation of array. So cast back to `char*` and use `[]delete`

**Q.3** yep, yes you can.

Comment: Q.2.: not true. it's UB.

Answer (score 0):

1. That seems correct. In a 32 bit architecture you most likely overallocated and only a portion of the memory will be used. In a 64 bit architecture most likely the two sizes are the same.
2. Neither one is appropriate. You allocated that memory as `char*` so you *must* delete it as such (by casting back to `char*` and then `delete[]`) or you have undefined behavior.
3. Line C won't compile because the two pointee types are unrelated. If you *did* use `reinterpret_cast` you would be violating the strict aliasing rules, again causing undefined behavior.